# Fastest ReplayBuffer using pytorch for DQN

Tags: algorithm, reinforcement-learning

I want to implement the class of ReplayBuffer but I don't know how to implement it so that it works extremely fast. Please help me.

I implement it use simple python list but it's very slow to learning atari breakout game.

Comment: there are a ton of numpy replay buffer out there, just pick one and you are close to optimal performance